# Api doc for Javascript 1.8.1?

Tags: javascript

Isn't 1.8.1 the latest version of Javascript?

Why is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript just giving you api doc for version 1.5?

Comment: Do browsers stay up to date with the language? I thought no. Anyone supporting IE can't use the latest JS anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because each version of JavaScript adds some features, but not much else is changed. For example, in JavaScript 1.6, several array-handling functions were added; hardly anything else was changed. Because of this, most of the documentation can be kept the same, though the MDC should probably update their version number on their documentation.

Changes in each version:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.5

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.6

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.8

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/New_in_JavaScript_1.8.1

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/New_in_JavaScript_1.8.5

Comment: But shouldn't they put the new things changed in the API doc? Is it for 1.5 only for 1.8.1? How do I know what's in 1.8.1 if they do not add the changes.

Comment: See my answer; I've updated it with links to the MDC changelogs for each new version of JavaScript since version 1.5.